# Naming public static final in lowercase?

Tags: naming-conventions, access-modifiers

I have a hierarchy of classes:

```
class Page {
}
class ChildPage1 extends Page {
    private static final String URL;
}
class ChildPage2 extends Page {
    private final String url;
}
```

Some pages have static urls but other don't. I need some methods like `load()` in parent class `Page` that will use url of it's descendant. I thought about implementing it in these ways:

- using reflection api
- naming static final URLs in lowercase (in conroversary to naming conventions).

Is it worth to not follow naming conventions in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding an abstract method `getUrl()` to `Page` that has to be implemented in `ChildPage1` and `ChildPage2`.

```
class Page {
    protected abstract String getUrl();
}

class ChildPage1 extends Page {
    private static final String URL;

    protected String getUrl() {
        return URL;
    }
}

class ChildPage2 extends Page {
    private final String url;

    protected String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to implement more than a hundred of pages. I'll should include this getUrl() method to every of these classes. Is it a good solution to create classes StaticPage and DynamicPage?

Comment: I doubt that it's a good idea implementing a hundred of classes for your different URLs. Maybe you should consider a different approach, e.g. by writing the URLs in a configuration file. If you still need to implement a hundred of classes you should use a code generator. Velocity is a simple to use templating engine that could do the job.

Comment: Method getUrl() in ChildPage1 should be static to access URL. If I want to create an instance of this class, I'll not be able to use getUrl() with this instance. Can I overcome this without using reflection?

Comment: Non static methods can access static variables, only the other way around is not possible. If you want `getUrl()` to override `Page.getUrl()` it must not be static.